# Rigify rest - pose position broken

Tags: animation, rigify

I have problems with rigify addon in blender. When rig is generated it have broken "pose position" and "set transform as pose position" button doesn't work. Help. 
Some screens
[image: Rest position]
[image: Pose position (you can see,that arms and legs are broken]

Comment: What do you mean with "have broken "pose position""?

Comment: Look at hands and legs at first and second screens. All bones from them compress into one small for some reason.

Comment: Have you verified your User preferences? User Preferences - File - Auto run python scripts: this one must be checked

Comment: Glad to help!! Have a nice day